# Can a SSL certificate generated with DNS hostname still be used if the URL to be accessed is the AWS ELB endpoint referred to by the DNS name?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, internal-dns

I have a self signed SSL certificate installed on an AWS ELB wherein another application accesses it via a URL using the DNS hostname defined on the certificate (test.sample.com). This is possible because the certificate was imported in the keystore of the J2EE app server that runs the app. Said app will now use the AWS ELB endpoint (ex. Internaltest-elb-aws.amazon.com) as hostname rather than the DNS hostname. Will this cause issues for the application accessing the other app via the load balancer with the SSL that refers to the DNS hostname initially?

Answer (score 0):

If application connects to public DNS name and certificate is issued to internal AWS name, client will get "Invalid Hostname" error and will refuse the connection. The certificate must be issued to a name client is used to connect to the server. So, in your case, either: get certificate for public name, or configure client application to use internal AWS name.

Comment: Thanks. Application connects to private DNS name with self signed certificate. Do i need to change my self signed cert? Original is issued to private DNS name, so if application is now configured to use internal AWS ELB, won't the ssl cert not match the URL that the application is trying to access? Thanks

Comment: Example cert is named to test.sample.com. test.sample.com points to internalelbaws.com. application points to lb with this cert using url https://test.sample.com/api and is working. Then using the same cert it will try to connect via this url = https://internalelbaws.com/api, will the app not get a certificate error?

Comment: `Then using the same cert it will try to connect via this url = internalelbaws.com/api, will the app not get a certificate error?` -- you will get error.